# What network interface is my VPN using

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, vpn

I'm trying to restrict internet access for a particular application. This is built in functionality but I can't seem to figure out what interface my VPN is using. Below is the list that is presented to me as options.

[image: Availible interfaces]

There is also a secondary question as to is there a way to clean up unused interfaces?